# How to add authentication to Mongo shard

Tags: mongodb, authentication, sharding

While trying add user to the MongoDB shard I am getting the Following Exception

> 2017-04-25T05:59:17.894+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't add user: not master
>
> at Error ()
>
> at DB.createUser (src/mongo/shell/db.js:1101:11)
>
> at mongo.js:1:4 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1101

How to add user to mongo Shard?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Need to configure Replica in Primary shard machine set by using

**rs.initiate()**

and then add shard in Query Router using

**sh.addShard()**

I Can able to add user on Shard by switching the DB before running the Add user command

**use admin**

using this you can able switch DB and then you can add user